# expected `;' before "pennies"? C++ Debugging (Code Completed)

Tags: c++, puzzle

Can anyone tell me why I get an error on my last `cout`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin>>ch; }

int main()
{
 cout << "How many pennies do you have?\n";
 int pennies;
 cin >> pennies;
 double total_pen;
 total_pen = (0.01 * pennies);
           if (pennies >= 1)
           {
                       string penn = " pennies.";
           }else
           {
                       string penn = " penny.";
 } cout << "How many nickles do you have?\n";
 int nickles;
 cin >> nickles;
 double total_nic;
 total_nic = (0.05 * nickles);
           if (nickles >= 1)
           {
                       string five = " nickels.";
           }else
           {
                       string five = " nickel.";
 } cout << "How many dimes do you have?\n";
 int dimes;
 cin >> dimes;
 double total_dim;
 total_dim = (0.10 * dimes);
           if (dimes >= 1)
           {
                     string ten = " dimes.";
           }else
           {
                     string ten = " dime."; 
 } cout << "How many quarters do you have?\n";
 int quarters;
 cin >> quarters;
 double total_qua;
 total_qua = (0.25 * quarters);
           if (quarters >= 1)
           {
                        string twentyfive = " quarters.";
           }else
           {
                        string twentyfive = " quarter.";
 } cout << "How many half-dollars do you have?\n";              
 int half_dollars;
 cin >> half_dollars;
 double total_dol;
 total_dol = (0.50 * half_dollars);
           if (half_dollars >= 1)
           { 
                        string fifty = " half dollars.";
           }else
           {
                        string fifty = " half dollar.";
           }
string saying = "You have ";
cout << saying pennies penn << "\n" << saying nickles five << "\n" << saying dimes ten << "\n" << saying quarters twentyfive << "\n" << saying half_dollars fifty << "\n"; 
keep_window_open()
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That indentation style is enraging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add more `<<`:

```
cout << saying << pennies << penn << "\n" 
     << saying << nickles << five << "\n"
     << saying << dimes << ten << "\n"
     << saying << quarters << twentyfive << "\n"
     << saying << half_dollars << fifty << "\n";
```

**EDIT**: Also, you are declaring variables in inner blocks - their names are no longer valid outside. Declare your strings earlier.

Comment: Im still getting errors on all my penn, five, ten, twenty and fifty variables

Comment: I figured out that the first time I declared the strings outside I never fully ended the line. My vault. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `<<` between the variables.

Try:

> cout << saying << pennies << penn <<
>   "\n" << saying << nickles << five <<
>   "\n" << saying << dimes << ten << "\n"
>   << saying << quarters << twentyfive <<
>   "\n" << saying << half_dollars <<
>   fifty << "\n";

**Update:**

The scope of some of your variables, such as `penn`, means they cannot be seen in the cout statement.

You need to declare the variables outside the if/else statements.

Also, as mentioned by @Color Bend, you are missing a semicolon after the `keep_window_open()` function.

Comment: That was the first thing I did and I actually got more errors then before.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `<<` between the strings and the numbers. It should read:

```
cout << saying << pennies << penn << ...
```

Comment: That was the first thing I did and I actually got more errors then before

Answer (score 2):

The statement `keep_window_open()` those not have a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the missing `<<`, your `penn`, `five`, `ten`, `twentyfive` and `fifty` string variables are all out of scope by the time you get to that cout.

You can't do this:

```
if (quarters >= 1)
{
    string twentyfive = " quarters.";
}
else
{
    string twentyfive = " quarter.";
}
```

As the string no longer exists when it leaves the scope of those braces.
If you want to do it like that you need to declare the variable outside the braces first.

```
string twentyfive = " quarter.";
if (quarters >= 1)
{
    twentyfive = " quarters.";
}
```

Or use the ternary operator to neaten it up:

```
string twentyfive = (quarters > 1 ? " quarters." : " quarter.");
```